# Simple Mvvm data binding - xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

Looks like I cant understand how exacly mvvm pattern works in xamarin.forms application. I want to make simple hello world application and its how I am doing this.

**ViewModel**

```
namespace HelloWorldApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _hello;

        private string hello
        {
            get { return _hello; }
            set
            {
                _hello = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel() {
            hello = "Hello world";
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SkanerDetali.Views.LoginPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:HelloWorldApp.ViewModels;assembly=HelloWorldApp">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding hello}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I cant figure it out what am I missing.. Any help would be highly appreciate

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but the C# Convention is to use a capital letter for the first name of properties ... `public string Hello {...}`

Comment: @Damian Yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `hello` property needs to be public.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _hello;

    public string hello
    {
        get { return _hello; }
        set
        {
            _hello = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tait's.. i am dump... lost  a planty of time.